# i have a form in laravel when i click on submit button it says token mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

when I click on submit button it gives an error token mismatch, I can't understand why it gives me this error

here is my rout

```
Route::get('admin-login', array('uses' => 'adminController@showlogin'));
// route to process the form
Route::post('admin-login', array('uses' => 'adminController@dologin'));
```

my controller

```
public function dologin(){
        $uname = Input::get('username');
        $password = Input::get('password');
        if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $uname, 'password' => $password))){
            return "success";
        }
        else {
            return "Wrong Credentials";
        }
    }
```

my form

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="">
                        <input name="_token" hidden value="{{ csrf_token() }}  " />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username">UserName: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password: </label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    </form>
```

here is error

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:
```

Comment: in showlogin method I just return form

Comment: Make sure your CSRF token is being sent, and that your sessions are working. This error is caused by a CSRF token not being sent or not matching what's in the session.

Comment: I do not have any token field in my table is this is an error?

Comment: The token field doesn't get saved to the database.

Comment: This works too :  {!! Form::token() !!}

Answer (score 0):

Please add `{!! csrf_field() !!}` inside your `<form>`.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">UserName: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

Don't use the `Input` facade. Better pass the `$request` object like this:

```
public function dologin(Request $request)
{
    $uname = $request->username;
    $password = $request->password;
    if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $uname, 'password' => $password))){
        return "success";
    }
    else {
        return "Wrong Credentials";
    }
}
```

Keep in mind to put `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` on top of your class.

Comment: and then it gives me a error form façade not found

Comment: The facade not found error likely comes from your `doLogin` method. Please insert `use Auth;` on top of your class - but this has nothing to do with your original question!

Comment: now it gives me a error Input not found App/http/controllers/Input not found

Comment: like thiss???? use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

Comment: I updated my answer - don't use the `Input` facade.